# completly uninstall apachectl on macOS

Tags: macos, apache, command-prompt, uninstallation

I installed via brew apache2 (`brew install apache2`), but uninstalled it later (`brew uninstall apache2`) but now the command `apachectl` is still left. how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple delivers an `apachectl` binary as part of `macOS`, so I suspect the one you are seeing is that one - and I certainly wouldn't advise you to delete it.

To check, run this in Terminal:

```
type apachectl
apachectl is /usr/sbin/apachectl
```

If you get the one in `/usr/sbin` like I do above, that is the Apple-supplied one. Leave it alone.

If you get something else, please click `edit` under your answer and update the question with the new information.